# Does a cursor store a SELECT result record-set in memory?

Tags: oracle, caching, plsql, database-cursor

From a book, I have read

> Whenever you perform a SQL statement, the Oracle opens an area of
>   memory in which the command is parsed and executed. This area is
>   called a cursor.

It applies both to explicit and implicit cursors. But I'm curious about another thing - can a  cursor be considered as a intermediate place (in memory) where Oracle returns final record set and uses it as a source for fetching records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cursor is a pointer to that intermediate set of data returned from the query. It contains state information for producing and accessing the result. From the [Concepts Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/memory.htm#BGBCICEI):

> A cursor is a name or handle to a specific private SQL area. As shown
>   in Figure 14-5, you can think of a cursor as a pointer on the client
>   side and as a state on the server side.

The result of a query is a `result set` and is pointed to by the cursor. It is stored in a temporary location, either in memory or on disk. From the [concepts doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/physical.htm#CNCPT1112):

> A temporary tablespace contains schema objects only for the duration
>   of a session. Locally managed temporary tablespaces have temporary
>   files (temp files), which are special files designed to store data in
>   hash, sort, and other operations. Temp files also store result set
>   data when insufficient space exists in memory.

Comment: Unlike an explicit cursor, which names the PL/SQL work area for the result set, a cursor variableis a reference to that work area.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle stores records retrieved from disk in a an area of allocated memory called the DB Buffer Cache.  But these are *blocks* of records which are then filtered to prepare a final result set.  Any other query on the same table can use these cached records rather than going to disk.  There's lots more on Oracle's memory architecture in the Concepts Guide.  [Read it here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/memory.htm#i10093)

Now what you're talking about is slightly different.  Oracle +can+ cache individual result sets.  At least it can since 11g, and only in the enterprise edition.  Obviously it only makes sense to cache sets for queries which are run frequently and whose results won't stale quickly.  There's no way the database can figure that out, which is why we have to tell it which result sets to cache.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/memory.htm#sthref1791).

Comment: :what happens when some open a cursor in one session without for update clause and someone from the other session update the records .Does this will affect the fetching of cursor ?

Comment: :i ll explain my question with steps 1)open a cursor for select * from emp where location='INDIA' in one session. 2)before fetching from  the cursor ,update emp set sal=sal+1000 where location='INDIA' ;commit;in 2nd session 3) fetch from the cursor update emp set sal=sal-200 ; commit;  Now the question is which session will update the records ?

Comment: @GauravSoni - that's a completely different question.  Transaction management has absolutely +nothing+ to do with memory architecture.

Comment: I read the question as asking whether the entire result set is materialized and stored in memory or on disk.  The currently accepted answer seems to be incorrectly saying that the answer to that is "yes".  Could you expand your answer to indicate that the result set doesn't, in general, need to be materialized on the server?